# Adobe Flex:change the text in <mx:text> with a click effect

Tags: apache-flex, text, click

I am new to flex, how do you change the text inside of a text control when a user has clicked a button. I could not find a way to do this. I used an event handler to input a .xml to a string and then to the text control. This doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

let's see if I can do this off the top of my head:

```
<mx:Button [all your button properties] onClick"buttonClick()"/>
<mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
    public function buttonClick():void{
      myText.text = "My new String";
    }
  ]]>
```

yeah, that should do it.